# Analytic Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Find the exact values.

$A)$ $\tan 60^\circ + \tan 225^\circ$

$B)$ $\tan 285^\circ$ (use $285^\circ = 60^\circ + 225^\circ$)

I'm just confused on how to do these kind of problems when they are in degrees, and when it is $\tan$. When it's $\tan$, don't you need to know at least of $\cos / \sin$?

Comment: Do you need help with part A or B or both?  What have you tried?

Comment: @PaulSundheim, I've tried part A, but looking at part B, I'm still confused

Comment: What did you get for A?  What did you try?

Comment: @Bye_World Well I thought since 60° is 1/3 of 180 it would be square root of 3 for tan and I have no idea for 225°

Comment: If you're not really familiar with the $\tan$, use $\sin / \cos$ instead.  If you're not really familiar with degrees, convert to radians.  You're right that $\tan 60^\circ$ is $\sqrt{3}$.  For $225^\circ$, you need to recognize that $225^\circ$ is just $180^\circ + 45^\circ$.  And how do $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions evaluated in region III relate to them evaluated in region I?

Comment: @Bye_World Thanks that's a huge help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the properties of the periodic function $\tan(x)$ we have:

$A)\ \tan(180^\circ+45^\circ)=\tan(45^\circ)=1$ and $\tan(60^\circ)=\sqrt3$

$B)\ \tan(285^\circ)=\tan(105^\circ)=-2-\sqrt3$